# How can I tell an Android app is aimed at tablets? Just Android version or something like iPhone/iPad

Tags: sdk, google-play, android

I'm building software that lists apps for users to test.

With respect to Android, how can you tell from an .apk that it is meant for Android tablets? Or does Android not make the distinction as iOS does with iPhone/iPad? I know iOS uses pixel perfect layouts (well points with retina) whereas Android uses much more of a liquid layout with much more different resolutions

I want to extract the .apk file and parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside the .apk (yes binary format, thanks Google) and determine if an app is suitable for only Android phones and/or Android tablets

Would checking for the existence of a drawable-large folder be one way?
Or the supports-screen element?

```
    <supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. Android doesn't have a concept of a tablet separate from any other device. They're all Android devices that just have particular characteristics. Focus on which characteristics you're interested in, such as screen size (as you have) and OS version.

Comment: yeah, thought so. Android market does not distinguish between phone and tablet apps. I guess there are apps out there that are heavily optimized for one kind of device, and then it will be up to the user to figure that out and determine whether they want to download the app

Answer (score 0):

From Google guide, if you can get these elements from the manifest file, this App can be considered declaring only for tablet.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Maybe this article can be helpful: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps